# How to logout an inactive user in django?

Tags: django

I want the session removed when the user is inactive for a certain period of time.

I tried `set_expiry(300)` and `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 * 60`, but the session was not extended even if the user was active.

Comment: **but the session was not extended even if the user was active.** - what do you mean by this? As `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 * 60` this should log you out after 300 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: The session is removed, even if the user is active or inactive for 300 seconds.If the user is active, I don't want the session removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the right setting for logging out part but your system is not informing the active requests to the session table, therefore system explicitly needs to save your new requests to session table which will updates timeout to expire.

In your `Settings.py`

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True     # opional, as this will log you out when browser is closed
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 300                   # 0r 5 * 60, same thing
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True          # Will prrevent from logging you out after 300 seconds
```